# What could cause uneven seasons?

Tags: science-based, physics, astronomy, seasons

A world's seasons have different lengths. Winter lasts for 33% of the year, Spring and Fall for 25%, and Summer for only 17%.

On the other hemisphere, it is the inverse. Is there any scientific explanation for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it physically possible for a planet to have seasons of different lengths?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-it-physically-possible-for-a-planet-to-have-seasons-of-different-lengths)

Comment: Seasons have different lengths in different places. How long is summer in [Tromsø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromsø#Climate)? How long is winter in [Timbuktu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbuktu#Climate)? How long is spring in [Bangalore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore#Climate)?