# Can a planet have asymmetrical weather seasons? Like 3 months for summer, fall and spring each and 6 months of winter?

Tags: planets, astronomy, seasons

I looked around for an answer and was unable to find it here. So can the planet have asymmetrical seasons? I want my imaginary planet to have winter doubled comparing to summer. And which astronomical conditions will provide this? Thanks!

Comment: 18 minutes for accepting an answer is a rather short time. If you wait at least 24 hours you might get more and better answers.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it physically possible for a planet to have seasons of different lengths?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-it-physically-possible-for-a-planet-to-have-seasons-of-different-lengths)

Comment: No, that question is about different lengths for one season in different years. Mine is about the constant season length over many years but different in length between each other.

Comment: Do you need a longer winter on the whole world, or just a large part of it?

Comment: The whole world should have a big winter

Comment: I see four answers in https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-it-physically-possible-for-a-planet-to-have-seasons-of-different-lengths that seem to apply.

Comment: A reminder to people considering a close vote: A fundamentally different question with similar answers is not a duplicate question.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-it-physically-possible-for-a-planet-to-have-seasons-of-different-lengths is a related question, but not a duplicate.

Comment: does the planet need to be habitable?

Comment: The United Kingdom.

Comment: *Planets* don't have seasons. A specific place on a specific planet has seasons. And there are many places on Earth where winter is longer than the other seasons; for example, how long are summers and winters in [Murmansk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmansk#Climate)? Conversely, there are *very* many places on Earth which do not have winter *at all*. How long is winter in Timbuktu?

Comment: Why do I think you're not from Canada?

Comment: If you can put physics aside, you can have a planet with an axial tilt that changes in time. This combined with some of the answers below (explaining the effect of the tilt) would give you the seasons you want, when you want them.

Comment: That is pretty much how it is here in Sweden.

Comment: Ah, Sweden... July, August, and Winter...

Comment: Winter is coming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

L Dutch's Answer does a really good job of explaining how Kepler's law of planetary motion works, but it is missing some pretty important details about axial tilt.

While the eccentricity of your orbit will make some seasons longer than others it will not affect your whole planet the same because while your Northern Winter may be longer, your Southern hemisphere could have a shortened winter and a longer Summer; so, this fails to get the desired effect on a whole Earth-like planet without messing with some other variables as well.

Technically, you could move the orbit enough so that you get the same season on both hemispheres of a tilted world, but this would cause compounding issues that would make one hemisphere uninhabitable. If your planet were to have an Earth-like tilt you'd have to make the orbit especially escentric to create an Earth-like "short summer" across the whole globe which would cause one of your hemispheres to experience twice the seasonal variance that you see on Earth.  So, while Earth's Temperate zone typically varies by about 40°C, a similar would with such an orbit would have a variance of 40°C in one hemisphere, and 80°C in the other.  While 80°C may not sound like too much variance for life to adapt to, it is certainly very bad for macro-organisms.  Your extreme temperature gradients and maximum temperatures reaching 60°C in one hemisphere will not just cause deadly heat, but massive storm systems including but not limited to [hypercanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercane) with wind speeds exceeding 800 kilometres per hour followed shortly by a long sub-arctic winter.  Tardigrades might get along just fine here, but macroscopic organisms generally take issue with silly things like freezing their body fluids, folding their proteins, and being ripped limb from limb.

[image]

For a more consistent "long winter" there are a few solutions that may yield the desired result:

One solution is to give your planet very little or no axial tilt with an eccentric orbit.  This would mean that your planet would not get seasons at all the way the Earth does, but only get seasons based on its physical distance from the sun.

Another way to solve your problem could just be to make your planet colder: either by reducing its greenhouse gasses or by moving it closer to the outer limit of the Goldilocks Zone.

While this second solution will not actually make the coldest time of year any longer than the warmest time of year, it would give you a longer winter from a biological point of view.  On a colder planet, plants and animals may need to be dormant for longer portions of the year waiting between when things are frozen and when they thaw out enough for macroscopic life to thrive effectively giving you a longer winter.

This second solution may be a better option if you want your civilization to still be able to rely on solar calendars to measure years since they sun always follows the same track in the sky on an untilted world.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite catch the same track in the sky part. Why the same track on the sky will cancel the sun calendar (Since on the Earth equator regions definitely use the calendar)?

Comment: With sufficient eccentricity, distance variation will override almost any amount of axial tilt.

Comment: @Bryozoa  The tilt of the axis means that the sun follows different paths through the sky at different times of the year.  Tracking these paths using various forms of sundials were how many civilizations built their early calendars and how early farmers knew when to plant/harvest/etc.  With no axial tilt, the sun would be in the same position in the sky during winter as in summer, just a bit dimmer because it is farther away.  Measuring the brightness of the sun is much harder by primitive means than measuring its position.

Comment: @Mark I will wait until the OP answers the "does the planet need to be habitable?" comment to respond to that question.

Comment: I would imagine removing axial tilt would have other effects on the planet that may affect the habitability of the planet.  Currents amongst other processes that have made Earth such a perfect home are affected by the axial tilt.

Comment: Also, 'I will wait until the OP answers the "does the planet need to be habitable?" comment to respond to that question.' - It would be good to understand how much axial tilt vs distance from the sun due to eccentricity has on the temperature of the planet.  It sounds like you're suggesting axial tilt would have a greater affect than distance.  This may be true, but it seems wrong.  Some equation/link/ect. would be helpful.

Comment: @c1moore Axial tilt plus eccentric orbits would cause compounding seasons; so, for one hemisphere to have a slightly cooler winter and warmer summer on a tilted world would mean dramatically colder winter and warmer summer on the other hemisphere.  This would make 1 hemisphere completely uninhabitable for macro-organisms due to temperature variation and the other hemisphere would still be harsh due to violent storms... presuming your hot summers on the other side of the planet does not just boil off your Oceans into a runaway greenhouse effect.

Comment: Sure, I get that, but if we're talking about an eccentric orbit that takes the planet to the edge of the Goldilocks zone, I imagine axial tilt would have a negligible effect.  You seem to suggest the opposite, that even that far out, the axial tilt could cause one hemisphere to be significantly (uninhabitably) hotter than the other.  Assuming a reasonable tilt (not ~90deg), I'm not sure I follow that train of thought.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Yes the planet needs to be inhabited

Comment: @c1moore details added to my answer based on the planet needing to be habitable.

Comment: bad image, the earth is closest of sun during winter... the distance to the sun is not the main composant to set temperature :)

Comment: @Matrix That is only true on Earth between the latitudes of ~23°N and ~66°N .  The Tropics and Polar regions do not have the same set of seasons as the temperate zones, and the southern temperate zone is inverted from the northern temperate zone; so, average weather actually is the main component.  SEE: https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2017-09-01/seasons-and-their-changes-explained/8858776 . The point of the diagram is to show what would happen if the orbit were eccentric enough to cause global seasons as the OP requested, not a realistic depiction of the Earth's orbit as it is.

Comment: ... unless your point was just that I tilted the Earth in the wrong direction based on the eccentricity of its orbit.  Since I was only meaning this to be an "Earth Like" world, it doesn't really matter as far as the answer goes, but still an informative catch.

Comment: Is it intentional that the diagram has summer matching summer and winter matching winter??

Comment: @AntonSherwood It's been a while since I made this, but I think so.  If the effect of eccentricity is greater than axial tilt, then both hemispheres will experience "Summer/Winter" at the same time.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Then shouldn't spring and autumn also be in phase?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Yes, I suppose they should.

Answer (score 33):

### Yes, asymmetrical seasons happen right here on Earth, when humans want them to.

The reason we have four seasons of equal length isn't because climate actually behaves that way. It's because humans find it convenient to divide the year up into smaller portions, and having four seasons of equal length is a simple way to do it.

In reality, climate changes throughout the year, and just because yesterday was "winter" and today was "spring" doesn't mean that suddenly all the snow is gone and all the flowers are blooming.

The European model of spring-summer-[autumn/fall]-winter, each lasting three months, is popular but there are many places where it's not terribly useful, and other models are acknowledged instead.

For example, Australian Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander peoples have developed [several different ways to describe seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_Australian_seasons), designed for the climates where those peoples live. In these systems, seasonal transitions are typically based not on fixed calendar dates but on specific events in weather and/or local fauna and flora, and there are often more than four seasons.

In Darwin, even among people with no Aboriginal/Torres Strait ancestry, the spring-summer-autumn-winter model isn't very helpful, and most people talk instead about the Wet and Dry seasons, sometimes with a third "build-up" season as Dry prepares to change to Wet.

In a place where snows last a long time, it's quite plausible that locals would define some kind of "winter" season that lasts much longer than a "summer" season. It's also very plausible that they'll come up with their own system of seasons that doesn't map neatly to the "cold, in-between, hot, in-between" categories that we're used to.

(Obviously though, you can't have six-month winter and three-month spring, summer, and autumn, unless your year runs for fifteen months. Or you allow seasons to overlap.)

Bottom line: "seasons" are a human fiction designed to split a complex reality into simple categories, and you are quite at liberty to tinker with just how that split is done.

Comment: Completely Agree. For another example, the Ancient Egyptians divided the year into three seasons - the flooding season, the growing season and the dry season.

Comment: Here on the east side of the Sierra Nevada, it's not uncommon to experience 3 of the 4 in the same day, and at the higher elevations it's possible (though global warming has made it less common than a few decades ago) to be able to ski as early as September and as late as July.

Comment: The way this answer starts seems to be basically saying "yes, if we define the words like that"? That allows an arbitrary number of seasons of arbitrary lengths, but needs to have no connection whatsoever to the actual weather/climate or the way the planet orbits its sun.

Comment: @ilkkachu That's overstating it a bit; if you reread, you'll see I mentioned a specific climate type which would make it plausible to have a long "winter" season. But since "winter" is a human construct that's only loosely connected to weather/climate, and since OP doesn't state what kind of "winter" is meant in this question, the question can't meaningfully be answered without leaning heavily on definitions. Orbital mechanics and climate can answer questions like "how do I get my world below freezing for six months of the year?" but that's not what the question asks. 1/2

Comment: @ilkkachu The question seems to presume that "winter" is intrinsically defined by astronomy, but that isn't really the case. Astronomy explains why there's a yearly temperature cycle but it doesn't explain why, where I live, "winter" is considered to run from June 1 to August 31, instead of some other set of dates. Those cutoffs are an arbitrary human decision. 2/2

Comment: Remember the old joke that Canada has only three seasons: June, July, and Winter.

Comment: Even in the UK, with no extreme climate, the natural weather-based seasons don't really coincide with the equal meterological definitions. I would say they are more like Spring = April and May, Summer = June, July, August, Autumn = September and October, Winter = November to March.(You could argue about whether November belongs in Winter or Autumn).

Comment: @alephzero And the date-based definitions of seasons don't keep up with changing climates, or El Niño/La Niña events.

Comment: Canada has 4 seasons: Hockey, mud, blackfly/mosquito, and Hockey Training Camp.

Comment: @KeithMorrison You forgot "construction".

Answer (score 22):

If your planet has a highly eccentric orbit, the time it will spend far away from the star will be necessarily longer than the time it spends closer to the star. Being further away it will also receive less light from the central star, thus strengthening the winter.

As you can see from this illustration of [Kepler's law of planetary motion](https://www.britannica.com/science/Keplers-laws-of-planetary-motion)

[image]

the distance covered during the orbit in the same amount of time changes with the distance from the star: the closer, the longer.

Comment: you do realize winter is not a global phenomenon right? the earth is actually closer to the sun during the northern winter.

Comment: @John, let it swing between 1AU and 3AU and it will be

Comment: Only if the planet has no axial tilt.

Comment: @John, take a comet. No matter its axial tilt, when it gets closer to the Sun will get way hotter than when it's at the further point from it.

Comment: hotter is not the same thing as summer. to compare imagine your planet with a 90 degree axial tilt, summer for one pole would still be winter for the other.

Comment: @John, picture a long-period comet with a 90-degree axial tilt pointed such that the southern hemisphere faces the Sun at periapsis: despite facing the Sun at apoapsis, the northern hemisphere will still be frozen because it's 80 AU away; conversely, the northern hemisphere will still be boiling at an 0.5 AU periapsis despite facing away from the Sun.

Comment: @Mark for a comet sure, for a planet however the darks side will be cold even if the planet itself is close to the sun. that is why the dark side of mercury is only 90 degrees K. also 80 AU is a much more extreme difference than the one proposed. also again hot =/= summer.

Comment: @John, any habitable planet is likely to have an atmosphere, which transports heat from one side to the other.

Comment: @Mark 1. no where does the OP mention the planet being habitable.  2 a planet with extreme eccentric will not be habitable, 3. this also depends on the atmosphere, the earths has a rather thin atmosphere.

Comment: Couldn't they just make 1 hemisphere all water? Then the "whole" planet has the same seasons as far as the inhabitants know.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I am no astronomer but it seems that this will be a global winter, not a hemisphere-based one. There will also be no tropical regions. I doubt this is what OP had in mind...

Comment: @John Yes, hot does not equal summer - *if* you define summer astronomically. Meteorologically, which is all the inhabitants will care about (and what the question is about), "hot season" is the definition of summer.

Answer (score 16):

It happens right here on Earth.  The temperate "four equal seasons" climate is actually an outlier:

- The equatorial tropics, particularly in the coastal areas, have a zero-season climate: the weather simply doesn't vary much from day to day.
- Deserts frequently have a two-season climate: "Wet" and "Dry", where Wet only lasts a few weeks.
- Alpine and sub-polar regions have a different two-season climate: "Winter" and "Growing", where Growing is the few months where snowfall is least common.
- Areas with a monsoon climate have three seasons: "Hot", "Dry", "Rainy" or "Hot", "Cold", "Rainy".  Rainy is shorter than either of the other two.

There are other variations, but these are the most common.

Comment: Speaking as someone who spent 40 years in the US Midwest, I can tell you that winter lasted at least 6 months and spring & fall each lasted about a month max. Especially recently. And I'm talking about snowing before Halloween then snowing off and on until April/May and sometimes into June. Then July-Sept were often scorching hot with bouts of rain, just to keep the humidity above 80%.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, if you define a season by what's happening rather than strictly according to arbitrary calendar divisions or astronomical data.

Let's define some terms, based on where I live: "Winter" is when there's minimal plant growth, low day temperatures (typically subzero), accumulation and maintenance of snow, and frozen standing water. "Spring" is when temperatures on average go above freezing, causing snowmelt and ice breakup. While frozen precipitation may still happen, it typically doesn't last. "Summer" is temperatures are above zero, there's maximum plant growth and animal activity. "Fall" is lowering temperatures, reduction in plant and animal activity, increased probability of frozen precipitation, and beginning of freezing of standing water.

Sound good?

Okay then, where I live, at sea level above the Arctic Circle in Canada, "Winter" begins at the start of October and lasts until May (roughly 6-7 months). "Spring" is typically the middle or end of May until June (1-2 months). "Summer" is July and August (2 months). "Fall" begins toward the end of August and September (1-2 months), and then in October, we're back into winter.

Answer (score 3):

One aspect of planetary motion that is not often thought about, since Earth is unsuaual as we don't really experience it like most orbital bodies do, but which might provide your answer, is gyroscopic precession.

Earth's primary orbital motions are to rotate and revolve. As I understand it, this is actually a peculiarity due to our moon having precisely the mass necessary to provide a stabilizing counterbalance, preventing Earth's axes from precessing, or swinging back and forth in a periodic manner as well. Most orbiting celestial bodies don't have this odd circumstance, and all three forms of orbital periodic motion are observed in them, not just the two with which we are most familiar.

I've read it theorized that the unusual stability of our axis is what kept our climate stable enough to allow life to evolve, without drastically changing regularly enough to periodically wipe all the critters out.

Overlooking this fact, you could probably posit some sort of gyroscopic precession arbitrarily changing the lengths of the seasons for a hypothetical planet to result in whatever asymmetry you'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the important  planetary climate discussed in other answers, you also may want to add sociological factors.

Nobody would bat an eye if I, an American, said that 'summer' runs from Memorial Day (the end-of-May long weekend) to Labor Day (the beginning-of-September long weekend).  Similarly, many people define 'winter' as the season of a winter sports league or a winter crop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily:

There are two ways a planet gets seasons:

Like earth, because the axis is tilted against the orbit. Summer in the north is winter in the south, etc. All seasons are symmetric, not considering local climate due to the geography (seas, deserts, mountains, etc).

Or like mars, which has a significantly more elliptic orbit, and the planet spends more time far away from the sun than close to it, giving a long winter and short summer. (Of course mars' axis is also tilted, giving long and cold winters in the south, and long and temperate summers in the north.)

So what you want is an elliptic orbit, and little axis tilt. Of course that gives planet-wide seasons, not alternating between the hemispheres.